# Removing all control and non-printing characters except newline, carriage return, tab and spacing

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Forgive me, but when I look at regular expressions it's like a goat staring at a new fence.

This (`/\p{C}+/u`) seems to work fine, but strips out newlines/carriage returns and tab:

```
$str = "
<pre>
    te" . chr(31) . "st

   test
</pre>
";

echo $str;
echo preg_replace('/\p{C}+/u', '',$str);
```

How would I leave those in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a try with:

```
$str = "
<pre>
    te" . chr(31) . "st

   test
</pre>
";

echo $str;
echo '=====================================',"\n";
echo preg_replace('/[^\P{C}\s]+/u', '',$str);
```

I've just negated the property `\p{C}` and add it in a negated character class that includes also all space characters.

Comment: I spent hours trying to figure out why everytime I tried to json_decode a string from a database it blew up. Finailly I narrowed it down to a specific record and figured that there must be a bad character somewhere in the string, I had to preserver newlines but wanted to remove the bad character that was blowing up the json_decode... and after hours of searching I found your answer that worked perfectly. It would haven taken me hours longer to fix this if you haddn't answered this 4 years ago. Thank you so much